# calendar reservation in react with valid and invalid dates?

Tags: reactjs

is it possible and exists a libary where I can make a calendar reservation from date X until Date X?

I know how to add this in backend and fetch it, but I want to know is there a libary where I can set my invalid dates that are reserved and display only the free dates.

Comment: This is not a question that should go on SO. However, just to give you a start, this is a library I've used in the past: https://www.npmjs.com/package/hotel-datepicker

Answer (score 0):

Check this library :
react-booking-calendar